# Regex Parsing HTML

Tags: regex, xhtml, attributes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

I would like to ensure that HTML attributes have quotes around them as is required by xhtml.

For example:

```
<BODY link=#0000ff vLink=#800080>
```

should be

```
<BODY link="#0000ff" vLink="#800080">
```

I am looking for a Regex pattern that would handle this.

Thanks

Comment: Parsing Html The Cthulhu Way, http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Comment: This site has over 100 questions about parsing HTML with regular expressions, all of which have the same answer: don't even bother trying; it doesn't work, and no matter how clever you get with your REs, it still won't work.

Comment: The `body` element is all lower case in the XHTML schema: http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1-schema/ XHTML is XML; if it fails validation, it's junk.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst not an exact duplicate, the basic answer is the same.

What you want is not regex, but a DOM parser.

Please specify your server side language. Or do you intend to do this with JavaScript? If so, there is not much point.

A suggestion too, if you are doing that to make it valid XHTML, then you should probably know the body element (and all the elements and attributes) are used in lowercase.